# JavaFXPorts, Gluon and ProGuard

Tags: ios, proguard, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I wonder if anyone can give an example of build.gradle file, showing how to use proguard for obfuscating the code compiled by JavaFXPorts? I thought it was done automatically, but stripping down the files created by JavaFXPorts proved that decompilation works just fine on the produced jars.